# PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "test"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm getting the same error as in the title:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(param varchar) RETURNS varchar AS 
  'BEGIN 
     LOCK public.routes;
     return (SELECT * FROM public.routes WHERE guid = 'test');
  END;' LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

What might be the problem? I can execute the same in console and it's gonna work.

Comment: Use " instead of `'` near `test` and check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape single quotes embedded in string literals by doubling them:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(param varchar) RETURNS varchar AS 
  'BEGIN 
     LOCK public.routes;
     return (SELECT * FROM public.routes WHERE guid = ''test'');
  END;' LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

That's the reason why people usually use [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) for the body of functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(param varchar) RETURNS varchar AS 
$body$
BEGIN 
     LOCK public.routes;
     return (SELECT * FROM public.routes WHERE guid = 'test');
END;
$body$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

---

However, even if you get the syntax right: the function will not work. It is defined to return a single (scalar) value of type `varchar` but it returns the all rows from the table routes. If you want to return multiple rows, you need to define the function as `returns setof` or `returns table`. In your case `returns setof routes` would be applicable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(param varchar) 
   RETURNS setof public.routes
AS 
$body$
BEGIN 
     LOCK public.routes;
     return (SELECT * FROM public.routes WHERE guid = 'test');
END;
$body$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

If you intend to return the value of a single column of a single row (assuming that `guid` is defined as PK or unique), then indeed `returns varchar` would work. But then you should change the select statement to `select some_column from ..` or something similar